# Pick four cards and check if they sum to 24 - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a program that picks four cards from a deck and computes their sum.
Note that ace = 1, jack = 11, queen = 12, and king = 13.  Upon computing their sum, check if that sum is equal to 24.  If it is, record that.  In the end, the program should display the number of combinations that sum to 24.

Here is what I have:

```
def selfour():
    total = 0

    cards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
             1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
             1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
             1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

    for a in range(52):
        for b in range(1, 52):
            for c in range(2, 52):
                for d in range(3, 52):
                    print(cards[a], cards[b], cards[c], cards[d])
                    if (cards[a] + cards[b] + cards[c] + cards[d]) == 24:
                        total += 1

    return total


def main():
    print(selfour())

main()
```

I'm not too sure if this program yield the correct answer, but it is inefficient.  If anybody can provide help to make this code more efficient, that would be great.  I'm fairly certain that this does not yield a correct answer, so help with that would be great, too.

Thanks

Comment: Is the correct answer 1291?

Comment: you might want to look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations to replace your nested loops.

Comment: One issue with the code is that while you (correctly) cant have a,b,c,d all equal (card index) 0, they can all equal (card index) 3, 4, 5, 6 etc.

Comment: @Goodies I'm not sure

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Itertools is your friend. You can do this in a one liner:

```
import itertools

cards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
         1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
         1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
         1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

def selfour():
    return sum(sum(i) == 24 for i in itertools.combinations(cards, 4))
```

Comment: `sum(sum(i)  == 24 for i in itertools.combinations(cards, 4))`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham answered too quick. Yours is cleaner. Editing.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking about the cards not being equal to each other, but you're not quite getting it.

```
for a in range(52):
    for b in range(1, 52):
```

needs to be something like:

```
for a in range(52):
    for b in range(52):
        if b == a:
            continue
```

There is a module called `itertools` that has `combinations` that does what you want. With it your nested for loops can become:

```
from itertools import combinations
for a in combinations(cards, 4):
    if sum(a) == 24:
        total += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is correct, but I was able to do:

```
from itertools import combinations
def sel(it, cnt=4, val=24):
    return sum(sum(_) == val for _ in combinations(it, cnt))

cards = # ...
print(sel(cards, 4, 24))  # => 12517
```

Edit: Sorry, I'm sure new answers have been posted. I was writing this as soon as it came up but got distracted before I posted it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using for the code:

```
import itertools

cards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
             1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
             1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
             1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
def selfour():
    total = 0
    for z in itertools.combinations(cards, 4):
        if sum(z) == 24:
            total += 1

    return total


def main():
    print(selfour())

main()
```

Thanks to help from users, this code is much more efficient and clean.

Also, other beginners can easily follow this if need -

-Thanks